# Can't install Paprefs

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to get two sets of stereos working, but everytime I try to install Paprefs, I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
```

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio-module-gsettings : Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1)
 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf : Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You've not told us what Ubuntu product/release you're using; which is essential for package issues as *deb* packages are built for specific releases. A quick CLI command and I can see `pulseaudio | 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 | jammy-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` thus issues won't occur if using *jammy* (22.04) but you've not said what you're using.  I'll suggest working out what product/release you're using and scanning the output of `sudo apt update` & contrast that with your release details (any warnings, missing lines etc)

Comment: Right.  My OS is Pop OS.  I'm trying to get multiple stereo's to work at the same time.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: Parts of your system are the same as Ubuntu, but you're not using a *stable* Ubuntu kernel, and you're using software Ubuntu treats as *testing grade* (ie. not ready yet for production systems thus not released for general use; available only should you enable -proposed as Ubuntu prizes stability) so you should be asking in a Pop forum where they are fully aware of what software stack you're using, or a site (SE *Unix & Linux*) which doesn't consider your question off-topic

Comment: Sorry folks.  I had no idea this forum was for Ubuntu only.

Comment: Please read https://apt.pop-os.org/