# How to install paprefs (PulseAudio Preferences)

Tags: apt, package-management, sound, pulseaudio, dependencies

Ubuntu 20.04

Installing `paprefs` gives the following errors:

```
sudo apt install paprefs
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 paprefs : Depends: pulseaudio-module-gsettings but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: pulseaudio-module-zeroconf but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


sudo apt -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true -o Debug::Acquire::http=true install paprefs
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) paprefs:amd64 < none -> 1.1-1build1 @un puN Ib >
Broken paprefs:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio-module-gsettings:amd64 < none | 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8 @un uH >
  Considering pulseaudio-module-gsettings:amd64 1 as a solution to paprefs:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed early because of libpulse0:amd64
  Considering pulseaudio-module-gsettings:amd64 1 as a solution to paprefs:amd64 9999
Broken paprefs:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:amd64 < none | 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8 @un uH >
  Considering pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:amd64 1 as a solution to paprefs:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed early because of libpulse0:amd64
  Considering pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:amd64 1 as a solution to paprefs:amd64 9999


sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-gsettings
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio-module-gsettings : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13 is to be installed
                               Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13 is to be installed
                              Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installed versions of `libpulse0` and `pulseaudio`:

```
apt list libpulse0 # check installed version of libpulse0
libpulse0/now 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13 amd64 [installed,local]
libpulse0/focal-security 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8 i386

apt list pulseaudio
pulseaudio/now 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13 amd64 [installed,local]
pulseaudio/focal-security 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8 i386
```

This seems to be a bug in `Ubuntu 20.04` because `libpulse0` with version `1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13` is already installed in the system but as described in the error message `pulseaudio-module-gsettings` and `pulseaudio-module-zeroconf` depends on `libpulse0` with version strictly equal to `1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8` (which is less than already installed)

Related questions:

- [Can't install Paprefs [Closed]](https://askubuntu.com/q/1498634/355121)
- [Unable to install paprefs](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2387112)
- [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/355121)

Answer (score 0):

Manual installation of `pulseaudio-module-zeroconf` and `pulseaudio-module-gsettings` with appropriate versions as deb files has solved the problem with dependencies for `paprefs`.
Libs for my configuration I found here:

- [pulseaudio-module-zeroconf_13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-universe-amd64/pulseaudio-module-zeroconf_13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb.html)
- [pulseaudio-module-gsettings_13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-universe-amd64/pulseaudio-module-gsettings_13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb.html)

deb packages installed with commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i pulseaudio-module-zeroconf_13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i pulseaudio-module-gsettings_13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
```

([How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/355121))

After that installation of `paprefs` with `apt` goes successfully:

```
sudo apt install paprefs
```

To run `PulseAudio Preferences` menu:

```
paprefs
```

---

There was problem with grayed out menu items in `PulseAudio Preferences` menu.

The following information helped:

`paprefs` searches of existing modules in `/usr/lib/pulse-13.99/modules/` but `Ubuntu 20.04` stores it in `/usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/`
Quick workaround:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/ /usr/lib/pulse-13.99
```

Related information:

```
I discovered the PulseAudio version (to set the 2nd arg to symlink cmd) with pactl --version.
I just have to remember to update the link after running apt-upgrade :-(

pactl --version
pactl 13.99.1
Compiled with libpulse 13.99.0
Linked with libpulse 13.99.0
--
paprefs would have never worked for pulseaudio versions x.y.z ( options would be grayed out )
It works only if pulseaudio version is x.y
```

Source: [All options grayed out on fresh install - Ubuntu Studio 20.20](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/paprefs/-/issues/7)